# SQL Choosing one address per person based on preference if they live in a certain state, otherwise the most current

Tags: sql, oracle

In my address table I have:
Unique_ID,  Address_Type,  Street,  City,  State,  Zip,  Effective_Date

Each Unique_ID can have multiple address types (which are 1L, 1P, AP, PO and AR).

I want to choose just one address per Unique_ID.

If the person has an address located in UT, I want to choose among all address types where UT is the associated State the one with the most recent Effective_Date.

Otherwise if none of the addresses are in UT, then I want the record with the most recent Effective_Date.

I thought about using CASE but it just returns a row for every address the person has when I need one row per person.

I have an Oracle table using SQL Plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Oracle and SQL plus use windowed functions, but this is how I'd do it in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
     Unique_ID, 
     Address_Type, 
     Street, 
     City, 
     State, 
     Zip, 
     Effective_Date
FROM    (   SELECT  
                *,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTIITON BY Unique_ID ORDER BY Priority, Effective_Date DESC) [Rank]
            FROM    (   SELECT  
                            *, 
                            CASE State WHEN 'UT' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS [Priority]
                        FROM    Address
                    ) [PrioritizedAddresses]
        ) RankedAdresses
WHERE   [Rank] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea.  The version of SQL Plus I'm using does support windowed functions.  However, when I try your code on the DENSE_RANK line it gives a "ORA-00923:  FROM keyword not found where expected" error.

I have used windowed functions a bit.  I'm an accountant who learns SQL by googling.  It seems like I'd need to use ROW_NUMBER to only end up with one record since there might be a tie in the Effective_Date (multiple address types added at the same time).

Comment: I sometimes have a hard time wrapping my head around inline views, which is what it seems you are using.  You can do the same things with CTE's - right?  Those make more sense to me to follow the logic of what is happening.

Comment: SELECT \*, other_columns_or_expressions syntax is not valid in ORACLE: you have to use an alias: SELECT a.\*, other_columns_or_expressions.

Comment: Hurray!  I had to make some adjustments, but got it to work.  Note:  PARTITION has a typo.  I tried to post my working code, but had issues with formatting and too many characters.  I just listed out each column name instead of the * - took out the brackets, it seemed like those were just column names - used ROW_NUMBER instead of DENSE_RANK - reworded "CASE State WHEN 'UT' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END" to "(CASE WHEN State = 'UT' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)".